# JavaScript: Order of defining functions and instantiating objects

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with the order of defining functions and instantiating objects, see: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yqdj5/)

I'm just playing around with an idea right now, but I hit this wall and I don't know if there's any simple solution to the problem. Basically I have a an object with some methods on another object, but this other object contains references to the first object and so no matter what order I instantiate/define I'll get an error because one or the other hasn't been loaded:

```
  var router = {
    update: function(event, from, to) {
      window.location.hash = "#/" + to;
      $("back-btn").disabled = fsm.can("back");  // *** And here I am referencing fsm
      $("next-btn").disabled = fsm.can("next");
    },
    location: window.location.hash.substring(2),
  }

  var fsm = StateMachine.create({
    initial: "intro",
    events: [

      // Next events and where to route based on our page
      { name: "next", from: "intro", to: "getname" },
      { name: "next", from: "getname", to: "welcome" },
      { name: "next", from: "welcome", to: "why" },

      // We can't go "back" from the initial route
      { name: "back", from: "getname", to: "intro" },
      { name: "back", from: "welcome", to: "getname" },
      { name: "back", from: "why", to: "welcome" } ],

    callbacks: {
      onintro  : router.update, //*** Here I am referencing the router object
      ongetname: router.update,
      onwelcome: router.update,
      onwhy    : router.update 
    }
  });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450997/resolving-circular-dependencies-with-dependency-injection  Also, here's a good question to check out regarding require.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639772/solving-circular-dependency-in-node-using-requirejs

Comment: Are you doing this all within the scope of JSFiddle, or are you testing somewhere else as well?

Comment: I'm testing in my browser without JSFiddle scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to assign the callbacks to the state machine object after the fact, and then defer initialization until after my router object was defined:

```
var fsm = StateMachine.create({

  //*** Here we set defer to true
  initial: { state: "intro", event: "init", defer: true },
  events: [

    // Next events and where to route based on our page
    { name: "next", from: "intro",   to: "getname" },
    { name: "next", from: "getname", to: "welcome" },
    { name: "next", from: "welcome", to: "why" },

    // We can't go "back" from the initial route
    { name: "back", from: "getname", to: "intro" },
    { name: "back", from: "welcome", to: "getname" },
    { name: "back", from: "why",     to: "welcome" } ],
});

window.onload = function() {
  var router = {
    update: function(event, from, to) {
      window.location.hash = "#/" + to;
      $("back-btn").disabled = fsm.cannot("back");
      $("next-btn").disabled = fsm.cannot("next");
    },
    location: window.location.hash.substring(2),
  }

  //*** And now we attach the callbacks since we have created the router object
  fsm.onintro = router.update, fsm.ongetname = router.update,
  fsm.ongetname = router.update, fsm.onwelcome = router.update,
  fsm.onwhy = router.update;

  //*** And call the init event!
  fsm.init();
}
```

and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yqdj5/1/)

Comment: Hm... Seems like a hack, doesn't it. =/ Does my recent edit not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the timing issue occurs because one of the callbacks you are specifying is `onintro`, which presumably runs right away. Is it practical to refactor your implementation for the `onintro` callback? You might be able to get away with something like this:

```
var router = {
    update: function(event, from, to) {
        window.location.hash = "#/" + to;
        $("back-btn").disabled = fsm.can("back");
        $("next-btn").disabled = fsm.can("next");
    },
    location: window.location.hash.substring(2),
}

var fsm = StateMachine.create({
    //...

    callbacks: {
        //onintro  : router.update, // Don't call this in the constructor...
        ongetname: router.update,
        onwelcome: router.update,
        onwhy    : router.update 
    }
});

router.update(); // Call it just after construct.
```

Comment: it actually throws the error before it even tries to callback, so when I comment it out it gives an error, here's a more JSFiddle friendly JSFiddle with the new version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/Yqdj5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `try/catch` to avoid the first undefined:

```
try {
    $("back-btn").disabled = fsm.can("back");
    $("next-btn").disabled = fsm.can("next");
} catch(e){}
```

Additionally, if you're testing all within JSFiddle, it's going to wrap your JS into a `window.onload` function. So when you click the buttons, they'll be trying to call `fsm.back()` or `fsm.next()`, where `fsm` was defined within the scope of that `window.onload` function. Not within the scope those buttons have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency fix could be as simple as:

```
var router = {
    update: function(event, from, to) {
        window.location.hash = "#/" + to;
        if(window.fsm) {
            $("back-btn").disabled = fsm.can("back");
            $("next-btn").disabled = fsm.can("next");
        }
    },
    location: window.location.hash.substring(2),
}
```

Comment: Ah, if I did this though, the button would be enabled and allow the user to access the back button initially when they shouldn't.  Thanks for all the help/ideas but it seems like I'm going to have to defer initializing the FSM, assign the callbacks, and then initialize the FSM, it's the only way I can see so far without having bugs.  It's just to test an idea out anyway, nothing that's hitting a wide audience (I don't think!)