# How to use one initialized Firebase Admin instance in multiple Node.js modules?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

SOLVED:
I was creating a circular dependency by simultaneously importing my worker modules into my Firebase config module to initialise them while at the same time importing my Firebase config module into my worker modules!!! Wow that seems stupid in hindsight, I was tearing my hair out!

So this is essentially a duplicate of this problem:
[solving circular dependency in node using requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639772/solving-circular-dependency-in-node-using-requirejs)

where I was bringing the workers in first then defining firebase second so it obviously wasnt defined at the stage of the worker modules being required.

original --------------------

In my client apps I tend to use a pattern of having one file where I initialize my Firebase App and then export that initialised app as a module which I can then import in other places. I'm trying this Firebase Admin in my node server but it keeps coming up as undefined.

What's considered the best practice for initializing the Firebase Admin app and then using that instance in other modules? 
Thanks

Edit: Added code sorry. I've missed a few steps but the firebase instance functions fine inside this file, I'm just having a problem exporting it.

```
 const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 const Admin = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: "my_credential",
  databaseURL: "my database"
 });

 module.exports.Admin = Admin;
```

Then elsewhere I'm trying to import that Admin and add refs to it etc like:

```
 const firebase = require('../myFirebaseModule);
 const Admin = firebase.Admin;

 const ref = Admin.database().ref();
```

But getting error that it's undefined. Or if I try and pull firebase admin in from the package rather than my module in another file, e.g

```
 const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

it says I need to initialise it. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe some code would make what you are trying to do a little clearer.

Comment: Can't reproduce this; it works for me.

Comment: oh wow thanks that made me realise it must be user error so I looked around. I just realised what I was doing wrong, I was simultaneously importing my worker modules into my firebase config file and initialising them in there, but at the same time importing the firebase config into my worker modules!!! I guess this is my first encounter with a circular dependency haha. It's working now, should I just delete the question? Or I can mark it as solved if you like and just explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Good to hear you've solved it. If there's a Node circular dependency answer in Stack Overflow somewhere - there should be - you could close this question as a dupe, referencing that answer. Otherwise, just answer your own question. (Note that closed questions are not necessarily deleted; questions that are not exact duplicates, but share the same answer are typically closed, but not deleted - as they function as signposts.)

Comment: Will close now thanks for your help!